# Why is my Texture origin is incorrect at runtime?

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, so this is the code:
Game1.cs Class:

```
 public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    KeyboardState keyboard;
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Player MyPlayer;
    Texture2D Ball;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        IsMouseVisible = true;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Ball = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Ball");
        MyPlayer = new Player(new Vector2(700, 700), Ball);

    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();
        MyPlayer.Update(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        MyPlayer.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Game object class:

```
 abstract class GameObject
{
    protected Vector2 position;
    protected Texture2D texture;
    public GameObject(Vector2 Position, Texture2D Texture)
    {
        position = Vector2.Zero;
        this.texture = Texture;
    }
    protected Vector2 Position { set; get; }
    protected Texture2D Texture { set; get; }
    protected float X
    {
        set { position.X = value; }
        get { return position.X; }
    }
    protected float Y
    {
        set
        {
            position.Y = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return position.Y;
        }
    }
    public int GraphicsWidth { set; get; }

    public int GraphicsHeight { set; get; }

}
```

Player class:

```
class Player : GameObject
{
    KeyboardState keyboard;
    bool IsJump = false;
    int SpeedX = 5;
    int SpeedY = 5;

    public Player(Vector2 position, Texture2D tex):base(position,tex)
    {
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get { return this.texture.Height; }
    }
    public int Width
    {
        get { return this.texture.Width; }
    }
    public void intialize()
    {

    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Position, Color.White);
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            X += SpeedX;
        }
        else if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            X-= SpeedX;
        }
        if (X > GraphicsWidth)
        {
            X = GraphicsWidth;
        }

    }

}
```

When I'm debugging it, My ball texture is in (0,0) (TOP LEFT). Instead of (700,700).

BTW, If anyone can give me some advices if I made anything wrong, or anything I should change, it Would be great!!

Thanks alot for helpers.

EDIT: Anyone.. please? I suppose it's not so hard to figure it out ><.

Comment: you need to call "base.Draw(gameTime);" before "spriteBatch.End();"

Comment: @Olle89 That is incorrect. While it may not crash, you generally aren't going to want to call into the inherited XNA functionality with an open SpriteBatch.

Comment: Made some edits to your questions.  Take a sec to see what I did thar.

Answer (score 1):

In your GameObject constructor you are setting the position to Vector2.Zero and not to your param Position.

```
public GameObject(Vector2 Position, Texture2D Texture)
{
    position = Vector2.Zero;
    this.texture = Texture;
}
```

should be

```
public GameObject(Vector2 Position, Texture2D Texture)
{
    position = Position;
    this.texture = Texture;
}
```

Comment: Yep, this one one of my mistakes. I figured the other one. Next comment:

Comment: Actually, didn't figure it yet, it's still same place (0,0)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues I see.  The first one, answered by CraigW, you've already fixed:

```
protected Vector2 position;    

public GameObject(Vector2 Position, Texture2D Texture)
{
    position = Vector2.Zero;  // <---- this needs to be position = Position
    this.texture = Texture;    
}

protected Vector2 Position { set; get; }
```

The second issue is your Position property.  When you declare a property using the { get; set; } syntax the compiler is implicitly giving you a backing field to store the value of the property. But you're creating your own position field as well. Your position field is getting set to the value passed in the constructor (assuming you've fixed issue #1 in your constructor that is), but the getter for your Position property is returning the compiler generated field, which you haven't set to anything.

There are two ways you can fix this. Either remove your position field and reference the Position property everywhere, or modify your property to use your position field.

Fix Option #1: just use the Position property

```
// protected Vector2 position;    // <----- remove this

public GameObject(Vector2 Position, Texture2D Texture)
{
  this.Position = Position;
  this.texture = Texture;
}
```

Fix Option #2: Change your Position property to use your field

```
protected Vector2 Position { get { return position; } set { position = value; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

-7? What did you do deserve this!?

I think there's a logic error somewhere in your code, change this:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Position, Color.White);
}
```

To this:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(700,700), Color.White);
}
```

And see how it works for you (it should work fine) :)

From there you're going to have to work backwards to find where Position is not being set to the value you want.

Personally I've never been a fan of gameobject, much better to create your own base types since you have total control over how they work and can more easily solve issues that pop up.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what he did? Create his own base class. GameObject is not a built in XNA class =)

Comment: oh my bad, I got it confused with GameComponent... Yeah his GameObject class doesn't look terribly impressive to me haha.